# Grid Control For ASP.NET similar to DBGrid in windows Forms

Tags: asp.net

I have an ERP system which has a lot of data entry screens like the one in the image. I want to shift my application from windows to Web. I need any similar solution. I searched a lot on internet but i am getting the same gridview controls with edit/add buttons .   I have seen in many systems such as SAP or Wipro HIS they have web application but screen and data entry grid same like windows 
[Image for Data grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXjcp.png)

Comment: Go for Telerik or DeveExpress Grid

Comment: Sorry they have the conventional methods. A gridview control with batch edit and add buttons . It is not reliable for me. I want something exactly like in windows forms DBgrid . I write something press enter goes to second row and so on.. It is much faster and reliable. I have many entries to pass in a day

Comment: i am wondering how online ERP systems are working there with scarcity of tools